# Numerable basis of holomporphic functions on a Torus

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I know that every holomporphic funcion on a Torus can be written in term of $\wp(z)$ and $\wp'(z)$. I'm however looking for a set ortogonal holomporphic function on $T^2$. That is, given an holomporphic function $f(z)$ on the torus, I would like to write it as

$$
f(z) = \sum_{m, n} a_{m, n} g_{n, m}(z) 
$$

And to determine the $g$'s. I know that using a Fourier basis this can be done, however that basis is not holomporphic.

Comment: I wonder whether $\wp(z;m\omega_1,n\omega_2),\wp'(z;m\omega_1,n\omega_2)$ would do the job

Comment: Orthogonal with respect to what inner product?

Comment: Orthogonal wrt *a* inner product. It should be included in the answer.

Comment: Holomorphic functions on the torus are always constant, you are talking about meromorphic functions. Any type of inner product defined by integral against some weight will not be finite for these functions.